# How to generate the Apollo sha256 hash?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I need to generate the sha256 string from a graphql query - without Apollo. Assuming my query looks something like:

```
query Foo {
  bar {
    test
  }
  bar2
}
```

How to properly format the string to match with the query in the URL? E.g. with/without white spaces, etc.

Ty